# Is wordpress good enough for ecommerce?

Tags: e-commerce

I'm familiar with Wordpress and some e-commerce back-ends like Magento, etc. I think I could build it with these, but I got advice not to do this as it will be hard to scale in the future. Should I listen to them?

Also, I will need custom features like custom product pages, user profile pages, voting elements, file uploads. Will I abe able to implement such features and more with wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all possible with Wordpress, and you have several choices. E.g. [WP E-Commerce](http://getshopped.org/) or [Jigoshop](http://jigoshop.com/) etc

Scale-wise, it depends exactly what you're wanting in terms of scale, initially and eventually. Wordpress can be manipulated to scale quite far, you can buy a bigger server, shift a large chunk of your content and pages into the cloud, appropriate caching and server setup, and the right plugins, can go a long way.

Your biggest issue if you code your theme correctly and set everything up, will not be server horsepower, it'll be network bandwidth, and that's not unique to Wordpress. The same issues will arise using Magento or Lemonstand etc